# Problems connecting Adafruit Feather M0 to network

Tags: arduino-ide, wifi, adafruit

I'm trying to connect my Adafruit Feather M0 board to an existing WiFi network. Whenever I use the "ConnectWithWPA" example sketch, I receive "Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: "MyNetwork" " in the serial window, where "MyNetwork" is the SSID for the WiFi I wish to connect to. The network never gets connected. The WiFi I want to connect is WPA, password protected. When I connect the feather to an open network (one without a password) it does in fact get connected. The problem only occurs when I try to connect to a network with SSID and password.

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>

#include "arduino_secrets.h" 
///////please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab/arduino_secrets.h
char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID;        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = SECRET_PASS;    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the WiFi radio's status

void setup() {
  //Configure pins for Adafruit ATWINC1500 Feather
  WiFi.setPins(8,7,4,2);
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid, pass);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid); //, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data:
  Serial.print("You're connected to the network");

 }

void loop() {
  // check the network connection once every 10 seconds:
  delay(10000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Feather board communicating with my WiFi network after I updated my Arduino IDE and firmware. Hope this helps anyone else facing this problem.